# Javascript set getter to class itself

Tags: javascript, getter

I have found a lot code to make getters and/or setter inside a class, but none to a the whole.
My intentions are to be able to do things like comparison (`new Time()>myTime`) etc.

```
function Time(hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds){
    // ...
    return this.format()
}

Time.prototype = {
    format: function(format){
        return this.replace(...) // return in HH:MM:SS MMM format as default
    },
    // other methods...
}
```

http://codepen.io/Akxe/pen/VYvPdj

Comment: Can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you want to implement `valueOf` and `toString`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: I think JavaScript doesn't handle operator overloading, so you will not be able to do comparison with the `>` operator. My advice is to create a method inside your `myTime()` class which take a `Time()` object in parameter and do comparisons inside.

Comment: May I suggest [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want custom comparison you can implement [Object.prototype.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf). This is used when coercing the object to a primitive when the <, >, + etc. operators are used.

Example

```
var Time = function (x) {
    this.x = x;
};
Time.prototype.valueOf = function () {
    console.log("valueOf() called");
    return this.x;
}

var a = new Time(1);
var b = new Time(2);

console.log(a > b);   // false
console.log(a < b);   // true
console.log(a + b);   // 3
console.log(a << 10); // 1024
console.log(a / b);   // 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks, nice to know.
But, what about time = time1 -new Time();?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support operator overloading (unless you happen to want to return a number), you'd have to have a subtract(date) method, i.e. time = time1.subtract(new Time())

Comment: Made it to return (new Date()).setHours(...).getTime() so I can do: new Time(time1-new Time())

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you need to let the object have a valueOf returning the total milliseconds, you could do as follows:

```
function Time(hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) {
    this.hours = hours;
    this.minutes = minutes || 0;
    this.seconds = seconds || 0;
    this.milliseconds = milliseconds || 0;
}

Time.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.milliseconds +
           this.seconds * 1000 +
           this.minutes * 1000 * 60 +
           this.hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
};
```

Then to compare Times, you could do:

```
var time1 = new Time(22,58),
    time2 = new Time(23,59);

if (time1 < time2) {
    console.log ("Yes, 22:58 is before 23:59");
}
```